# Why i am getting errors while onCreate() method?

Tags: android

i try to implement AppFlood advertising into my project. I do it with [this tutorial](https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/papaya-download/sdk/Documentation/Splash+Screen+SDK+Integration+guide-20140516.pdf) . I got into the onCreate() method and then i get multiple errors. First i make imports and get warning The import com.appflood.AppFlood is never used. After this i tried to Initialize AppFlood Object and Splash screen. And after that i get synatx errors.

This is my MainActivity:

```
import com.appflood.AppFlood;
import com.appflood.AppFlood.AFEventDelegate;
import com.appflood.AppFlood.AFRequestDelegate;

public class onCreate();
AppFlood.initialize(this, "Your app key here", "Your secret key here", AppFlood.AD_ALL);

public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication implements MyRequestHandler {
    private GameHelper gamehelper;
    private MyGdxGame mygdxgame;
```

Comment: but your `oncreate` isnt a method, it's a class. How does it even compile?

Comment: Neither a method nor a class. Check syntax for both in java documentation.

Comment: its inside the  class we have to call  methode

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't read the document in full concentration. It said "InitializeAppFloodObject in your onCreate() method and before setContentView() is invoked ". Which means in your main activity there is an overridden method. 
Example :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // place here
    AppFlood.initialize(this, "Your app key here", "Your secret key here", AppFlood.AD_ALL);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_car_detail);
}
```

Read the rest of the tutorial carefully.

Edited : I pasted full code without error. Extend your class from activity.

```
public class Test extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // place here
    AppFlood.initialize(this, "Your app key here", "Your secret key here", AppFlood.AD_ALL);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_car_detail);
}}
```

Comment: But if i insert it i get errors: 
        - void is an invalid type for the variable  onCreate
 - Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
 - Syntax error on token ")", ; expected

But now i almost understand it.